# Determining statistical significance of a repeated measures t-test

Tags: self-study, t-test

#### Scenario:

An industrial/organizational psychologist is interested in determining whether adding 15-minute breaks increases worker productivity.
She selects a sample $n$ and measures productivity (on a continuous scale) before and after introducing the intervention.

The researcher runs a repeated measures t-test.

#### Question

- How can I work out whether the intervention is effective?

Comment: -3.15 of what?  By itself, that number is meaningless.

Comment: I've changed the question to make it less of a homework question.

Comment: @tom- the t test is a way to measure the difference between two groups..specifically the mean of two groups. You can perform this test and see whether the t value is large enough in the t table of significance.In your case the variable to measure would be productivity.

Answer (score 1):

You just use a generic t-test with matched pairs. For each worker, measure before and after. Use a one-sample t-test to test whether the difference between these two measurements is zero.

I've actually never before heard anyone use "repeated measures" to refer to fewer than three measurement times. Repeated measures gets more complicated when you have three measurement times, which may make the question's phrasing sort of scary.